# How to use boolean intersect with two plans and the mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
These are two plans I want to cut to only keep the outside of the vertical plane. There is a mirror modifier applied on z axe. I tried to use the 
Boolean Intersect Tool. So my question is how to use one plane (object) as a cutter to cut away from another plane (object).

[image]
I removed the mirror modifier and tried with 3D object but nothing happens as I hit CTRL+ F key Intersect(Boolean). I tried with the Intersect knife tool and "No Intersection found" diplays.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's quite hard to tell from your screenshot, where exactly the mirror modifier is. Either add another screenshot that shows the mirrored object in Edit Mode or consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and adding the given link to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the problem: *Boolean Intersect* (and *Knife Tool*)  work only if the objects are joined.

Comment: Actually, that's not the case. Boolean works just fine with two separate objects. The result depends on how exactly both objects overlap.